# Mapbox Databinding package missing

Tags: mapbox

Trying to import com.mapbox.maps.databinding.ActivityViewAnnotationShowcaseBinding
to my project but some reason 'databinding' is not available.
Original code is here https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/view-annotation-showcase

Gradel

```
    plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'

}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.navmap"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {

}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
    dataBinding true
}


}

 dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.2.2"
implementation("androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0")
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10"

// new install
implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'
implementation "com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2"
implementation "androidx.databinding:databinding-runtime:7.3.0-alpha07"
implementation "androidx.databinding:databinding-adapters:7.3.0-alpha07"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks